# How to get 10k fillings for the russell 3000 constituents using sec-api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, edgar

Is it possible to fetch the 10-K filings using something like the following?

```
from sec_api import QueryApi

query_api = QueryApi(api_key='YOUR_API_KEY')

# Define search parameters
index_ticker = 'RUA'  # Russell 3000 index ticker symbol
filing_type = '10-K'
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2020-12-31'

# Build query
query = {
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {'match': {'indexTic': index_ticker}},
                {'match': {'formType': filing_type}},
                {'range': {'filedAt': {'gte': start_date, 'lte': end_date}}}
            ]
        }
    },
    'size': 10
}

# Send query and get results
results = query_api.get_filings(query)
```

In the [response format](https://sec-api.io/docs/query-api), I don't see any information on the index. Therefore should I approach it in the following:

1. Get the constituents of the [Russell 3000 index](https://content.ftserussell.com/sites/default/files/ru3000_membershiplist_20210628.pdf)
2. Fetch 10-K filling for each

```
from sec_api import QueryApi

query_api = QueryApi(api_key='YOUR_API_KEY')

# Define search parameters
ticker = 'AAPL'
filing_type = '10-K'
start_date = '2020-01-01'
end_date = '2020-12-31'

# Build query
query = {
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [
                {'match': {'ticker': ticker}},
                {'match': {'formType': filing_type}},
                {'range': {'filedAt': {'gte': start_date, 'lte': end_date}}}
            ]
        }
    },
    'size': 10
}

# Send query and get results
results = query_api.get_filings(query)
```

As you can see, this solution seems to be inefficient.

Comment: If you're modifying your code for each ticker, yes that's inefficient. Maybe parse your list for all of the tickers programmatically and get all of the filings that way? At the end of the day, you are downloading thousands of 10k filings, this isn't going to be fast or efficient